# How to make UIDatePicker change month automatically when day changes from 31 to 01?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

As the questions says I need the picker to switch the month automatically when day is changes from 31 to 01, also the year should switch when the month changes from December to January or vice-versa.

For instance:

31.01.2020 -> change day to 01 -> 01.02.2020

31.12.2020 -> change day to 01 -> 01.01.2021

I wonder if there is any property I could activate.

For now I only have a simple DatePicker

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

        datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
        
        datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
   
        self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker){
        
        let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
        
        let selectedDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        
        print("Selected value \(selectedDate)")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: The number of days in any given month is based on a set of rules.

Comment: You can get month from calender and always set day to 1.

Comment: You need to make a custom picker.

Comment: It sounds like the picker you're talking about is one whose `datePickerMode = .date` and whose `preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels`

Comment: I'm guessing you want this for an added bit of user convenience? It may not even be worth doing this. Besides, the default picker style (as of iOS14 I think?) has a completely different interface and looks nothing like the traditional day-month-year wheels. Maybe you find the new style more convenient? Unless you specifically want to use the old style and augment it?

Comment: @PeterParker The new picker solves the issue, but I need this for older versions where .wheels style is used

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. It's a quick hack, since there's no property you can set to enable it automatically.

[image]

The `UIDatePicker` *doesn't* have any `UIControl.Event` that we could add a target action pair for, to inform us of continuous value changes while we're scrolling. And it's `date` property only updates when it's come to a complete stop. So...

Basically I use a `Timer`, and pull the info out of the subviews, detect when day wrapped around, determine whether the month should incr or decr, and then I call `scrollToRow(:)` on the month `UITableView`.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    
    var picker: UIDatePicker!
    
    var currentMonth: Month? {
        didSet {
            if let oldValue = oldValue, oldValue != currentMonth {
                print(currentMonth!)
            }
        }
    }

    var currentDay: Int? {
        didSet {
            if let oldValue = oldValue, oldValue != currentDay {
                print(currentDay!)
                
                if [28, 30, 31].contains(oldValue) && currentDay == 1 {
                    print("Incr the month!")
                    self.incrMonth()
                } else if oldValue == 1 && [28, 30, 31].contains(currentDay) {
                    print("Decr the month!")
                    self.decrMonth()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func incrMonth() {
        let cell = self.monthTableView.visibleCells.last!
        let indexPath = self.monthTableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: 0)
        self.monthTableView.scrollToRow(at: newIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
    
    func decrMonth() {
        let cell = self.monthTableView.visibleCells.last!
        let indexPath = self.monthTableView.indexPath(for: cell)!
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row - 1, section: 0)
        self.monthTableView.scrollToRow(at: newIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
    
    var monthTableView: UITableView!
    var dayTableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        picker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 200))
        picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        picker.datePickerMode = .date
        picker.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(picker)
        
        // The wheels style picker consists of 3 dials.
        // The month, day, year dials are each represented by not one, but two `UITableViews`.
        // One for the top half of a dial and one for the bottom half, which is interesting.
        // The last visible cell of a top half tableview is always the highlighted one.
        
        monthTableView = self.picker.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UITableView
        dayTableView = self.picker.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UITableView
    
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { _ in
            let monthLabel = self.monthTableView.visibleCells.last!.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UILabel
            let dayLabel = self.dayTableView.visibleCells.last!.subviews[0].subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UILabel
            let day = Int(dayLabel.text!)!
            self.currentDay = day
            self.currentMonth = Month(rawValue: monthLabel.text!)
        }
        
        // So the timer won't be blocked by UI interactions
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
    }
}


enum Month: String {
    case January
    case February
    case March
    case April
    case May
    case June
    case July
    case August
    case September
    case October
    case November
    case December
    
    func number() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .January:   return 1
        case .February:  return 2
        case .March:     return 3
        case .April:     return 4
        case .May:       return 5
        case .June:      return 6
        case .July:      return 7
        case .August:    return 8
        case .September: return 9
        case .October:   return 10
        case .November:  return 11
        case .December:  return 12
        }
    }
}
```